# Using mgt-loader to load the profile information

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Even after authentication I am unable to see my profile getting loaded. It still shows sign in even after authentication.

I am using link **http://localhost:5500/** and same is used in Redirect url.

[image: Azure App configuration]

After authentication I see only below screen. Could you please suggest what I am doing wrong to get authenticated.

[image: Browser Screeshot]

Comment: It looks like it is working. You've explicitly specified that you wanted it to redirect to localhost5500 after successfully authenticating. what you should do instead is redirect to another page in the application (i.e. HomePage) or dynamically change the UI depending on if the user is signed in.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details on your authentication method (custom provider)?

First try the following, If you use the mock provider are you able to receive profile information. Render this to the page using:

```
<mgt-mock-provider></mgt-mock-provider>
```

Please let me know of the results.

Comment: I am using  "mgt-msal-provider " for authentication

Comment: Great, can you please implement the above provider and let me know if you have similar results? This is a mock profile, which wont require auth to use. 

I'm trying to narrow down the point of failure.

Comment: I could able to with some changes to the authentication in Azure AD.